# Storing output data (numbers) into XML/json file format - to develop graph

Tags: c++, json, xml, opencv

I am working in Computer Vision domain, coding completely in C++ using OpenCV API, I have found results and printing the values in cmd prompt. I wanna save these results(basically integers and floating point numbers)  in XML file and then develop a graph (bar charts or line graphs)- basically a web dashboard(GUI). Now I am in a stage, such that I use, **ofstream** and save the data in a csv/xml file. But it just prints the value same as such in cmd prompt.

**Can someone kindly help me with a technique to store the values in XML tree structure? so that I will create a web dashboard(bar graphs) with that xml data**

I have also came across msxml6,tinyxml,libxml++ but have not got any fruitful results.

Thanks in advance - please provide link to the other question if this is a duplicate.

The code sample :

```
    #include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>

    int main ()
    {
    cv::VideoCapture capVideo;
    capVideo.open("video.mp4");

    cv::Mat imgFrame1;
    cv::Mat imgFrame2;

    double fps = capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    std::cout << "FPS = " << fps <<std::endl;

    double fc = capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    std::cout << "Total Framecount = " << fc <<std::endl;

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("theBigDataSheet.xml");
    capVideo.read(imgFrame1); 

    int frameCount = 1;
    while (true)
    {
    int divisor = fps*15;

    if (frameCount%divisor == 0 || frameCount==fc-1)
    {
       if (frameCount<fc-1)
       {
       outfile << frameCount/fps << std::endl;
       outfile << frameCount << std::endl;
       }
       else{
       outfile << frameCount/fps << std::endl;
       outfile << frameCount << std::endl;
       }
     }
    if ((capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) + 1) < 
         capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) 
        {
            capVideo.read(imgFrame2);
            frameCount++;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "end of video\n";
            break;
        }
        cv::waitKey(33);
       }
       outfile.close();
        return(0);
      }
```

see the code : at every 15th second, it will print the framecount, and the seconds - finally it will print the final number of frames and seconds - i need to plot this as a graph (which will be a linear line)

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code.

Comment: @logic-unit - please check the code, i have posted it.